# How to compute and calculate this probability?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let:

$k\in\Bbb Z$ ($\Bbb Z$ is the set of all integers)

$n\in\Bbb N$ ($\Bbb N$ is the set of all natural numbers (positive integers) and does not own/contain 0)

$\vec{c}\in\Bbb Z^n$ ($\Bbb Z^n$ is the cartesian product of the set $\Bbb Z$ with itself $n$ times)

$\vec p\in\Bbb R^n$ ($\Bbb R^n$ is the cartesian product of the set $\Bbb R$ with itself $n$ times)

$\Bbb R$ is the set of all real numbers.

All elements, terms, coordinates and components of vector $\vec p$ are greater than 0 and less than 1.

$\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}:x_i\sim\text{Bernoulli}(p_i)$

How to compute and calculate:
$\text{Probability}\Bigg(\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^nc_i\cdot x_i=k\Bigg)$?

When all the elements of vector $\vec c$ are equal to 1, all the elements of vector $\vec p$ are equal to some real number in the unit interval $q$ and $k\in\{0,\ldots,n\}$ then the sum of all the $n$ bernoulli variables distributes binomial distribution with probability $q$ and number $n$ and then the probability in question is $\displaystyle\binom{n}{k}\cdot q^k\cdot(1-q)^{n-k}$, **but** I want to know the **general** and **universal** formula to compute and calculate the probability in question without the constraints and restrictions specified below the question.

Comment: Notice that only special types of $k's$ are allowed. The answer is a lot dependent upon what is your $c$ and $k$ because it matters in how many ways you can break your $k$ in terms of some set of $c's$